Bursts of concurrent queries in JMeter
I want to simulate a number of concurrent users (50), each of which may fire off a number of concurrent queries (10) at random intervals.
The purpose of the test is a BI dashboard scenario, where users may randomly refresh the dashboard, and each refresh triggers a number of queries.
The Thread Group gives me concurrent users, the Uniform Random Timer gives me random delays, but I can't figure out how to concurrently trigger the queries within the thread group.

If you're talking about simulating AJAX requests when 1 user refreshes the dashboard causing 6 simultaneous calls - this is not something JMeter can do out of the box.
However this form of network footprint can be simulated with Parallel Controller which is JMeter Plugin. It can be installed using JMeter Plugins Manager

I wasn't clear that these are database queries, but I think the Parallel Controller might be the solution. Thank you.

Or, you could just run a full browser instance

I'm running database queries, so a browser isn't much help. Sorry that wasn't clear from the question.
